# Как создать маску для датафрейма по списку подходящих значений в колонке?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask

Есть датафрейм по продажам автомобилей. Каждая строка соответствует событию продажи автомобиля. Одна из колонок - "dealers". В ней указаны дилер, осуществивший продажу. Я хочу сделать маску для датафрейма, которая оставит только строки, соответствующие дилерам, указанным в списке. Как правильно это сделать? Как правильно сформировать маску? Пытался через in:

`mask = sales['dealers'] in list_of_dealers`

Выводит ошибку:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: `mask = sales['dealers'].isin(ваш список)`

Comment: @АлексейР спасибо огромное! А есть ли аналогичная функция, только наоборот, чтобы оставить строки со значениями, НЕ входящими в данный список?

Comment: Нужно просто инвертировать эту маску оператором ~ (тильда)